# Convert function for on-the-fly calculation?

Tags: python, time-series

I have the following function :

```
x = ln( Sum_k (1/sqrt(t_k)) )
```

k = 1 .. n

In python :

```
def signal(t):
  rv = []
  ts = np.array(t)
  ts.sort()
  for i in np.arange(1,ts[-1]*3):
    tick = np.log(1 + np.sum( 1/ np.sqrt(i - ts[ts < i])) )
    rv.append(tick)
  return np.array(rv)


 plot(signal([10,20,30])
```

[image]

this is the key :

```
 i - ts[ts < i]
```

difference between current tick and all previous "spikes".

In this case I had all the times at which signal is introduced i.e. t => 10,20,30 ... I want to reformulate the function in such a way so that I can calculate it as the time proceeds dynamically without storing all the "spikes", so it works for "infinite"-signal

==========

The time "ticks" discretely ... then once in a while I receive "spike" ...now at every tick I have to calculate the current value of the resulting signal .. I can not store the time "t" at which the spike happened, because soon I will have to use too much memory, because I'm calculating multiple signals with spikes happening at different times.

```
def recv(self, spike_yes_no ):
   i = self.tick
   .... calculate ...
```

Comment: not really related, but if you are just trying to iterate over indices, don't use `np.arange`, use the builtin `range`. `np.arange` **builds an array**, which is big overhead, and then has to "box" values every time you get the next value, which is *slow*.

Comment: Hmm, in what way do you plan to be receiving a stream of data like that?  And what exactly do you mean when you say that you don't want to "store" the previous data?